# Unable to create a new dashboard in ckan using ckanext-wirecloud

Tags: fiware, ckan, fiware-wirecloud

I have installed ckanext-wirecloud extension in my CKAN. However, while creating a new view we have an option of "create a new dashboard" as shown in the image attached.

But while creating it, I am unable to do so, because the data tab Axis X and Axis Y are not able show any data and I am not able to click anything in it.

[image: ds]

Comment: what kind of data are you trying to display using to build the dashboard? Currently, this extension is able to display data stored using the datastore plugin on CKAN or data stored in a context broker server.

Comment: Yes, I have a CSV dataset that is stored using datastore. And then for the same-resource I am creating a new "wirecloud-view". So, for this I am creating a new dashboard.